# How can I get rid of as much oil from my schnitzel after deep-frying it?

Tags: frying, deep-frying

My issue with my favorite food is that it has so much oil in it. I'm using simple sunflower oil to deep-fry my schnitzel and it comes out delicious, but it has too much oil in it.

I use napkins to dry as much as possible but it doesn't do a great job.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome! What temperature are you frying at?

Comment: Don't deep-fry.

Comment: @Cindy I believe it's ~200C. It's an old oven, so it doesn't show, but I remember closely following them a few years ago. Does it matter?

Comment: You are deep-frying in an oven?

Comment: @paparazzo Na, just a plain ol' deep pan.

Answer (score 7):

Heat your oil to 375 F (190 C).  Use a oil or candy thermometer to make sure you maintain that temp.  Fry your schnitzel.  Once cooked, make sure to drain by holding over the pan...or use a basket or skimmer to shake excess oil from the cooked schnitzel.  Remove as much excess oil this way as possible.  Move to absorbent paper.  The combination of the right temperature, and removing excess surface oil will help greatly.

Answer (score 6):

Bread is really good at soaking up oil. You can use dried bread, and then make croutons after it has soaked up the oil.

When I was in a navy galley, we used to make schnitzels for 120 people. After the basket, they would go in a big pan lined with slices of day-old bread.
The bread soaked up the oil, and after all the schnitzels were done, we would add garlic to the bread and let it dry in a low temperature oven for an hour.

I'm honestly not sure if this was done in order to soak up the oil, or in order to make use of the old bread, but it works as both anyway.

Comment: Wow! I had forgotten about that. Many years ago some of the local seafood restaurants would serve fried seafood on top of dry bread. It was well understood that the bread was not to be eaten. It was just better at absorbing any excess oil.

Comment: How come the temperature matters so much for not getting a lot of oil stuck on it? And oh yea, the bread trick actually works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get rid of excessive oil is not to add it in the first place...

Therefore add some oil in a [misting or spray bottle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gouWM.jpg) and spray a little bit of oil on both sides of the schnitzel or add a slice of butter on top and then put the schnitzel in the oven at 175°C (347°F) until nice and crispy.

Comment: I've experimented a lot, but it seems you need a lot of oil to get that crunchyness, especially on the sides, otherwise, it just ends up burnt.

Comment: I live in Germany and that's how I make my Schnitzels: spray some oil, turn around, spray some more, 175°C and depending on the thickness, 20-30 min convection while you cook the other stuff. @coolpasta (If I'm in a hurry, just add a nice slice of butter on top, it'll drizzle off the sides and underneath...)  Also: The meat should be juicy and the crust should be crunch

Comment: I suspect it absorbs more oil that way.

Comment: @Gigili it doesn't really, *because there is less to absorb*  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Use an air-fryer at 350F (Usually takes 10 min pre heating and 25 min t till it turns light golden brown. Then shallow fry it instead of deep frying. Turns out Less oily and just as crispy as its supposed to be.